# .NET 5 Routing with Parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-core-5.0

I have two simple pages and would like to pass some parameters from one to the next. I get an error with the current code:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
> Unhandled exception rendering component: Unable to set property 'ManufacturerID' on object of type 'PortalUI.Pages.CategoriesPage'. The error was: Specified cast is not valid.
> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to set property 'ManufacturerID' on object of type 'PortalUI.Pages.CategoriesPage'. The error was: Specified cast is not valid.
> ---> System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.

The pages are as follows (in order of execution)

```
@page "/machines/manufacturers"
@inject HttpClient Http
@inject NavigationManager NavManager

<h1>Manufacturers</h1>

<p>Display all manufacturers in the database</p>

@if (manufacturers == null)
{
    <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
}
else
{
    @foreach (var i in manufacturers)
    {
        <a @onclick="((args) => Navigate(i.ManufacturerID))">
            <ManufacturersBox Name="@i.Name"
                              ImgURL="@i.ImgURL" />
        </a>
    }
}

@code {
    private Manufacturers[] manufacturers;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        manufacturers = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<Manufacturers[]>("https://localhost:44335/api/Manufacturers");
    }

    private void Navigate(int ManufacturerID)
    {
        NavManager.NavigateTo($"/machines/manufacturers/{ManufacturerID}/categories");
    }
}
```

And the page I want to pass to

```
@page "/machines/manufacturers/{ManufacturerID}/categories/"

@inject HttpClient Http
@inject NavigationManager NavManager

<h3>CategoriesPage</h3>

<p>This page belongs to @ManufacturerID</p>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public int ManufacturerID { get; set; }

    private Categories[] categories;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        categories = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<Categories[]>("https://localhost:44335/api/ManufacturerCategories/" + ManufacturerID);
    }
}
```

I've tried using an href in the link instead of using NavigationManager (which I would prefer as it allows users to view the URL at the bottom of their screen before clicking) but both give the same answer.

Now considering that I am not getting the default 404 Page not Found error of .NET I assume something is happening, I am just messing up somewhere.

Additional info: 
My UI is a Blazor WebAssembly App 
My Business Logic is the API you can see at OnInitializedAsync()

Comment: Also, @ErikPhilips. Thank you for the edit, will keep it in mind in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set `@page` as follows:

```
@page "/machines/manufacturers/{ManufacturerID:int}/categories/"
```

The Router pulls the parameter from the url as a string and passes it to the RouteView component which tries to pass a string to the component as the `ManufacturerID` parameter.

The above change tells the Router to capture the value as an int.

See - [Ms Docs - Route Constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0#route-constraints)

Comment: Thank you, this really was it. I swapped over to href instead of NavigationManager as well. One last question as they don't really say in the docs. Why did it not work without the constraint? The value passed still was an integer, it just didn't know that it was one?

Comment: See my updated answer.  There are two approaches to route parameters - tell the router what to convert the "string" to, or always pass them as strings and then do your own casting/conversion to an internal property.